# инсталлятор для программы, работающий с СУБД MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

Программа разработана в visual studio С# она работает с СУБД MySQL. Как при помощи Setup Project создать инсталятор который кроме самой программы устанавливал бы еще и СУБД(если она отсутствует)?

Comment: СУБД это - система управления базой данных (один клиент или группа клиентов для манипуляций с данным на сервере). А сервер mysql это сервер, а не субд)

Comment: А зачем вам использовать на локальном компьютере MySQL, если есть безсерверные базы данных, которые специально сделаны для работы на локальном компьютере.